# Google Places API without HTTPS

Tags: php, api, https

I am having problems sending requests to the Google Places API because my machine is behind a proxy with authentification. I successfully worked around this in the past by using a context when sending http requests from PHP. I have trouble getting this to work with HTTPS from Google places and the easiest way would be to just use HTTP.

I cannot find the link for the HTTP API. The basic URL for requests is: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/output?parameters

(source: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/).

I am looking for a way to connect to this API without using https. Just using http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/output?parameters results in a 404.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2):

You should write 'json' or 'xml' instead of 'output' in url.

like http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?..